# `gcc.exe' failed in phase `C Compiler'. (Exit code: 1)

Tags: haskell, gcc, haskell-stack

When Cabal or Stack install hackage the error message like title.
Full mes is:
cabal install ghc-mod
realgcc.exe: error: C:\Users\浠ユ亽\AppData\Local\Temp\4118467.c: No such file or directory
realgcc.exe: warning: '-x c' after last input file has no effect
realgcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
`gcc.exe' failed in phase`C Compiler'. (Exit code: 1)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing 'stack setup--reinstall'. I had a similar message cleaned up this way.