# cabal install `gcc' failed in phase `C Compiler'

Tags: haskell, gcc, cabal-install

I want to use `parsec` for a personal project. But when I invoke `cabal install parsec`, I get an error:

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-no-pie'
gcc' failed in phase `C Compiler'. (Exit code: 1)
```

I am on OS X El Capitan, 10.11.6. If I have understood correctly he error message above, `gcc` seems to be the cause. When I check the version of `gcc`, I get

```
gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
```

Besides, I have read this [`gcc.exe' failed in phase `C Compiler'. (Exit code: 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839260/gcc-exe-failed-in-phase-c-compiler-exit-code-1) and after `stack setup--reinstall`, `stack install parsec` worked very well. But cabal always not. Can you help me?

Comment: If you can install through Slack, why are you trying to install it through cabal ? Have you put parsec as a dependency of your project ? (In the cabal file or package.yaml file, depending on which version of Slack you use) In which case, you should be able to use parsec as a dependency (or test it in an interpreter launched using `stack ghci`).

Comment: Did you try updating Xcode to the latest version (this will also update clang)?

Comment: Thank you for your kind replies.

David Young> I must update the computer system in order to update Xcode. I will try it after exam time. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same problem in the same time :-)

Most answers I’ve found on stackoverflow is about to update Xcode.

**But!** I’ve seen that suggestions since 2013, and in that case, I can’t update Xcode, because I have old Macbook and OS X 10.11 on it, i have tried:

`brew install gcc`

Next step I wondering how to setup Gnu C Compler over Xcode and found right now how.
Open in terminal with your fav. editor:

`mate /Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/8.4.2-x86_64/usr/lib/ghc-8.4.2/settings`

And change this:

```
, ("C compiler command","gcc")
, ("C compiler flags"," -fno-stack-protector")
, ("C compiler link flags"," ")
, ("C compiler supports -no-pie","YES")
, ("Haskell CPP command","gcc")
```

with `/usr/local/bin/gcc-8` instead `gcc` & `"NO"` instead `"YES»`

Hope it helps <3

Comment: Spend 3 days on it and still can't make SublimeHaskell works properly 

Comment: Just setting -no-pie to "NO" did it for me (everything else works with clang). Thanks!

Comment: managed to fix that warning by editing `settings` in `~/.stack/programs/...` folder. This is where stack installs `ghc` to isolate it from system `ghc`